# Combining two objects to give you one more elaborate one

Tags: unity, c#, gameobject

I'm looking for some help to someone throw me a light on this problem I'm having.
We're making a clothing game where you got to grab a "cloth" and a "string" and bringing them to the sewing table to give you one sort of garment.
We've already made a list of items but are not sure of how to combine them, what you get in return, or even how to detect which one is the one you have grabbed.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to detect that there actually are a string and an cloth near the sewing table at the same time. I would do that by adding [colliders](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html) to all of them and making the collider of the sewing table a trigger.

I would then write a script for the sewing table which uses the [`OnTriggerEnter`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerEnter.html) and [`OnTriggerExit`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerExit.html) event methods to keep track of which items are currently within the trigger area.

When that script detects that both a cloth and a string are present, then I would use the [`Destroy`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html) method to remove both of them and then use the [`Instantiate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) method to spawn the garment item as a new game object.